# Make Chart.js horizontal bar labels multi-line

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Just wondering if there is any way to set the horizontal bar labels for y-axis using chart.js. Here is how I set up the chart:

```
<div class="box-body">
<canvas id="chart" style="position: relative; height: 300px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext("2d");
    var options = {
        layout: {
            padding: {
              top: 5,
            }
        },
        responsive: true,
        animation: {
            animateScale: true,
            animateRotate: true
        },
    };

    var opt = {
      type: "horizontalBar",
      data: { 
        labels: label, 
        datasets: [{ 
        data: price, 
        }] 
      }, 
      options: options
    };

    if (chart) chart.destroy();
    chart= new Chart(ctx, opt);

    chart.update();
```

As you all can see, the first and third labels are too long and cut off. Is there a way to make the label multi-line?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the following chart plugin :

```
plugins: [{
   beforeInit: function(chart) {
      chart.data.labels.forEach(function(e, i, a) {
         if (/\n/.test(e)) {
            a[i] = e.split(/\n/);
         }
      });
   }
}]
```

<sup>add this followed by your chart options</sup>

**ᴜꜱᴀɢᴇ :**

add a new line character (`\n`) to your label, wherever you wish to add a line break.

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'horizontalBar',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan\n2017', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'BAR',
         data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.7)'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      }
   },
   plugins: [{
      beforeInit: function(chart) {
         chart.data.labels.forEach(function(e, i, a) {
            if (/\n/.test(e)) {
               a[i] = e.split(/\n/);
            }
         });
      }
   }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hmm but the problem is I am populating the labels dynamically so I could not hard code the \n into the string.

Comment: do it when saving labels to the database.

Comment: This solved my issue, thank you! A illustrated description of this approach can be found here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/2704#issuecomment-372637124

Comment: is there any way to do multiple line label(after push) and update the chart?

Comment: @PAR you can use `beforeUpdate` function while update the chart.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to have full control over how long labels are broken down across lines you can specify the breaking point by providing labels in a nested array. For example:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
...
  data: {
    labels: [["Label1 Line1:","Label1 Line2"],["Label2 Line1","Label2 Line2"]],
    datasets: [{
...
});
```

Comment: it displays as [object, object] in my situation when I use nested array

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial you may need to convert your array using map function.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with object syntax? `datasets: [{data: [{x: 10, y: 20}, {x: 15, y: null}, {x: 20, y: 10}]}]` I tried putting an array instead of a plain string and it didn't work.

Comment: How could I set different styles for label 1 line 1 and label1 line 2?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately provided answers work only with static data, so I wrote simple JS function specificallly for dynamic texts, it splits label into arrays with defined line length limit:

```
function splitLabelForChart(label) {
  const words = label.split(' ');
  const lineLimit = 14;
  const lines = [];

  let line = '';
  let currentWordIdx = 0;

  while (currentWordIdx < words.length) {
    if (line.length + words[currentWordIdx].length < lineLimit) {
      line += `${words[currentWordIdx]} `;
      currentWordIdx++;

      if (currentWordIdx === words.length) {
        lines.push(line);
      }
    } else {
      if (line.length) {
        lines.push(line);
        line = '';
      }

      if (words[currentWordIdx].length >= lineLimit) {
        lines.push([words.currentWord]);
        currentWordIdx++;
      }
    }
  }

  return lines;
}
```

And how it's used:

```
const chartData = {
    labels: data.map((e) => splitLabelForChart(e.label)),
    datasets: [
      ...
    ],
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with @GRUNT here. As I was adding plugins in options here I was getting confused on how to add plugins here. Here we need to add an id for that custom plugin. Sharing my snippet.

```
createChart(data: any){
    var labels = <string[]> Array()
    var dataset = <number[]> Array()
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      dataset[i] = data[i][0] 
      labels[i] = data[i][1] + "\n("+ data[i][2] + ")"
    }
    this.chart = new Chart("MyChart", {
      type: 'line', //this denotes tha type of chart
      data: {// values on X-Axis
        labels: labels, 
           datasets: [
          {
            label: "Tax",
            data: dataset,
            backgroundColor: 'limegreen',
            borderWidth: 4
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        aspectRatio:3.5,
        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Top 10 TRP Tax Collection'
            }
        }
      },
      plugins:[{
        id: 'customPlugin',
        beforeInit: function(chart) {
          if(chart.data.labels)
          chart.data.labels.forEach(function(e:any, i, a) {
             if (/\n/.test(e)) {
                a[i] = e.split(/\n/);
             }
          });
       }
      }]
    
    });
  }
```