# Chart.js xAxis bottom label alignment

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

My chart.js bottom label looses it center alignment when I line break it into two lines
and when my labels are rotated to 90 degrees

MY Xaxis code

```
        xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            afterFit: function (scale) { scale.height = 170; },
        

            stacked: true,
            gridLines: {
                display: false,
                borderDash: [2, 6],
                color: "black",
            },
            ticks: {
                fontColor: "#4A4A4A",
                fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                fontSize: 14,
                fontStyle: 600,
                maxRotation:90,
                minRotation:90,
            }
        }],
```

[image]

Comment: Don't do manual line breaks. Do what this answer suggests instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54411781/12057512

Comment: I also would love an answer to this question. Having the exact same issue. I tried what the previous comment suggest but sadly without success.