# Y axis labels are getting cut off on horizontal bar chart in Mobile view + ChartJS v4

Tags: chart.js, vuejs3, bar-chart, nuxtjs3, vue-chartjs

I have a Nuxt 3 application with Vue 3. I am using composition API with typescript. In my `package.json` file I have the below dependencies:

```json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^4.2.1",
    "vue-chartjs": "^5.2.0",
  }
  ...
}
```

When the charts are rendering my y-axis labels are cutting off in mobile view. Please see image below.

[image]

My vue component code is as below:

`MovieHorizontalBarChart.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div class="chart-container">
    <ClientOnly>
      <Bar :data="data" :options="chartOptions" />
    </ClientOnly>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  ChartOptions,
} from "chart.js";
import { Bar } from "vue-chartjs";

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

const data = {
  labels: ["Label 1", "Very very very very long name that is cut off"],
  datasets: [
    {
      axis: "y",
      label: "Count",
      backgroundColor: "#000",
      data: [10, 24],
    },
  ],
};

const chartOptions: ChartOptions<"bar"> = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  indexAxis: "y",
  plugins: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Horizontal Bar chart by ChartJS",
      font: { size: 14 },
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 25vh;
}
</style>
```

QUESTION: The `Very very very very long name that is cut off` label gets cut off. How can I get my y-axis label to appear on multiple lines? Or is any other approach where I can avoid the labels getting cut off?

NOTE: The labels are dynamic. I do not know before hand how long the each label will be. Every new external API request will generate new values. My actual labels code is as below:

```js
const data = {
  labels: props.movies.map((movie) => movie.name),
  datasets: [
    {
      axis: "y",
      label: "Count",
      backgroundColor: "#000",
      data: props.movies.map((movies) => movie.count),
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make Chart.js horizontal bar labels multi-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451451/make-chart-js-horizontal-bar-labels-multi-line)

Comment: I have seen this before and I tried this answer in the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/45451821/9621971. However, I am not sure how to make this code work in vue 3 using chartJS v4 code as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the labels as an array of string or string[].

See doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html#category-axis-specific-options

In your case:

```
const data = {
  labels: ["Label 1", ["Very very very", "very long name", "that is cut off"]],
  datasets: [
    {
      axis: "y",
      label: "Count",
      backgroundColor: "#000",
      data: [10, 24],
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: However, the labels are dynamic. I don't know before hand what labels I would get. It can vary everytime I make a new external API request. I actually have the labels code as `labels: props.movies.map((movie) => movie.name)`.

Comment: Maybe you could apply a logic in map callback to wrap the text with max label length